# How to find common articles between two specific articles in Wikipedia?

Tags: links, wikipedia

I have two articles A and B, and I want to find any articles in the path from A to B. Is there a tool to do this?

There are several tools to list **the shortest path**, such as [WikiDistrict](http://wikidistrict.com/), but I would like to have more paths, maybe three shortest ones.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would know how to do this - in awk. But have other priorities. If you want, the fundamentals of retrieving the backlinks can be found in the Media Wiki Awk API. https://github.com/greencardamom/MediaWikiAwkAPI .. then create an algo to traverse backlinks X layers deep. Keep in mind this could end up querying millions of API backlink calls, it could be significantly time consuming and expensive. But if it was kept to 2 or 3 layers deep max like in the diagram that would help.

Comment: would this be a quick method? I'm familiar with Linux, but I don't have it at hand. Also, how much time would it take for coding Awk specifically?

Comment: Program speed is I/O bound so C or whatever won't help. Awk is probably the easiest language to learn, I don't know how long it would take depends on your skill level. Maybe a couple days 5-10 hours? A lot of the work is already done with this API and backlinks.awk .. just need add the algo logic to recurse through the pages and check for matches efficiently.